# Handling exception in calling a external api

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm calling Udemy external api to build a simple REST service for experimental purpose.

https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/

Here is my get_all() courses method.

```
class Courses(object):
    """
    Handles all requests related to courses.
    ie; gets the courses-list, courses-detail, coursesreviews-list
    """

    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        logger.debug("courses initialized")

    def get_all(self):
        page = 1
        per_page = 20

        while True:
            res = self._get_courses(page, per_page)
            if not res['results']:
                break

            try:
                for one in res['results']:
                    yield one
            except Exception as e: -->>>handling exception
                print(e)
            break

        page += 1

    def _get_courses_detail(self, page, per_page):
        resource = "courses"
        params = {'page': page, 'per_page': per_page,
#                   'fields[course]': '@all'
                  }

        res = self.api.get(resource, params)
        return res
```

Now, is it reasonable to handle a exception(in get_all() method) assuming that there could some error in the returning data of the api?

Or handling the exception(in get_all) is not needed here and it should be handled by the calling function?

Most of the open source projects that I see don't handle this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing the opinion in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/231059). So catch the exception as soon as possible and rethrow it if needed to the next layer.

> With practice and experience with your code base it becomes quite easy to judge when to add additional context to errors, and where it's most sensible to actually, finally handle the errors.
>
> Catch → Rethrow
>
> Do this where you can usefully add more information that would save a developer having to work through all the layers to understand the problem.
>
> Catch → Handle
>
> Do this where you can make final decisions on what is an appropriate, but different execution flow through the software.
>
> Catch → Error Return